# Navigating through an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Hello I have this array and I seem to forget how to naviagte through it.

```
Line* line = (Line*) malloc(sizeof(Line)*line_count);
for (int i = 0; i <line_count; i++){
(line + i) ->blocks = make_blocks(block_count);
(line + i) ->block_count = block_count;
```

}

Logic:

Line is a pointer to the start of this continuous block of memory. I want 
to adjust the line pointer by 1 (the size of the line) and make blocks for 
that specific line and set the block count.

The above (line + i) does not work 
I have tried line[i] (line + i)*  &line[i]
but still nothing

Can anyone show me the light ? Its really dark where im sitting.

Thanks

Comment: It's more normal to use `line[i].blocks`, but `(line+i)->blocks` should work.  Perhaps something else is wrong?  You ought to tell us exactly what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: give us a clue as to what goes wrong. This code is basically correct

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is of the type Line. You can´t point to blocks like that.

For that you would need to have an array of pointers to type blocks (if that´s a type/struct you made).